# JUnit tests works in IntelliJ but fails on eclipse and build server

Tags: java, azure, appium, appium-ios

I'm just confused why the same test works in IntelliJ but not in Eclipse or the Azure build server.
It would help to share the code I think, I just fill out a login Page and click some buttons.

For some reason that's to fast for eclipse and the build server, but I why it works normally on IntelliJ?

I'm new to IntelliJ and I also tried to disable the JUnit Plugin, but this won't help because you can't run any test without it.

EDIT: I also tried it in VS Code, with the [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and it works the same way like in Eclipse.
I don't know what is different to IntelliJ, but something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason but I guess the problem is that IntelliJ is a little bit slower then the other IDE's on executing JUnit tests / or slower when using Appium.